# python is getting global modules instead of local ones inside of virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

This is my first time using virtualenv and MySQLdb and I'm getting a strange error. After I setup this virtualenv, I installed MySQLdb from within the virtualenv (with the ENV actually activated). MySQLdb is not installed globally. When I'm in my ENV folder, open a python terminal, and try to import the module I get the following:

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

However, when I do the same thing from the site-packages folder

...ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages

> > > import MySQLdb

everything seems to work just fine.

Also, when I run

> > > help ('modules')

from either directory, I get very slightly different lists (even though it's telling me I'm using the same python executable). It's like for some reason the same python executable is getting it's modules from different places and the only time it's getting the modules it's supposed to have is deep inside the ENV, in this case the site-packages folder. If I'm not in the site-packages folder, it seems to get a different list and I get no access to MySQLdb.

I'm using Mac OSX Mavericks, XCode is up to date to the best of my knowledge (I don't find I use it very much).

I used this to setup the virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python ENV
```

`which python` gives me this both in ENV and in site-packages

> ...ENV/bin/python

Versions

virtualenv version 1.11.6
python 2.7.8 (not the default python)

### UPDATE:

Installed sqlalchemy

```
(ENV)tims-mbp:ENV timbauer$ pip install sqlalchemy
```

And am getting the exact same affect. It seems like even though it's using the correct python when inside ENV, that version of python only is getting the correct module list when it's directly inside the site-packages folder. Otherwise it looks like it's pulling from the global list

Comment: How and from where did you install the *MySQLdb* module?

Comment: I used pip to install the MySQLdb module from within ENV. I had the virtualenv active when I did it. MySQLdb isn't installed globally.

Comment: Did you specifically invoke the *pip* from the *virtualenv* into which you wanted to install the module?

Comment: Yes, I did. And apparently I have to type at least 15 characters to answer that. :P

Comment: Installed sqlalchemy

(ENV)tims-mbp:ENV timbauer$ pip install sqlalchemy

And am getting the exact same affect. It seems like even though it's using the correct python when inside ENV, that version of python only is getting the correct module list when it's directly inside the site-packages folder. Otherwise it looks like it's pulling from the global list.

Comment: Still having issues. See solution and comments. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Inside ENV/bin/pip there was a line that said this

```
#!/Users/timbauer/Desktop/ENV/bin/python2.7
```

That needed to say this

```
#!/Users/timbauer/Desktop/ENV/bin/python
```

Switching the above out and restarting terminal seems to have fixed everything. I had to delete the virtualenv and reinstall everything to get it to work, but I'd just barely started so this wasn't really that big of a problem.

Comment: Yay! New issue. Same as the old one. import pony won't work inside virtualenv unless I'm either in the site-packages folder or I use python2.7 instead of python. When I realized this second bit yesterday, I went in and changed the pip file as mentioned above and that fixed everything. Well, that obviously isn't causing this problem because the changes I made yesterday are still in effect. Not a project killing problem, but super, super, annoying...

Comment: Odd thing is when I did a full delete and reinstall from scratch, making sure all #! headers ended with python instead of python2.7, no change for import pony. BeautifulSoup works just fine from anywhere, but import pony only works if you use python2.7 or are inside the site-packages folder...